# Try with exception logging

Tags: scala, exception, logging

Scala's `Try` is very useful.

I'd like to use that pattern, but log all exceptions.

How can I do this?

Comment: I will come back and write an official answer later. However, here's a blog post I just finished addressing just this issue (and others related): http://fromjavatoscala.blogspot.com/2016/09/rethinking-scalautiltry.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Define the following helper:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Failure}

def LogTry[A](computation: => A): Try[A] = {
  Try(computation) recoverWith {
    case e: Throwable =>
      log(e)
      Failure(e)
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as you would use `Try`, but any exception will be logged through `log(e)`.

Comment: Will try out.  BTW, to match Try source code https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala#L192 , shouldn't it only catch NonFatal exceptions?

Comment: @SRobertJames - No, because it already has only caught NonFatal exceptions, so there are only those to recover from.  Unless you mean: can I log all exceptions from Try _including those it can't catch_?  Then the answer is no; you have to insert your own custom logging code.

Comment: This solution will not emit logging if the `Throwable` is !NonFatal.

Answer (score 8):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the chaining operation [`tap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#tap[U](f:A=%3EU):A) can be used to apply a side effect (in this case some logging) on any value while returning the original value:

```
import util.chaining._

val x = Try("aa".toInt).tap(_.failed.foreach(println))
// java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "aa"
// x: Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "aa")
```

Or an equivalent pattern matching version:

```
val x = Try("aa".toInt).tap { case Failure(e) => println(e) case _ => }
// java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "aa"
// x: Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "aa")
```

---

The [`tap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#tap[U](f:A=%3EU):A) chaining operation applies a side effect (in this case `println` or some logging) on a value (in this case a `Try`) while returning the original unmodified value on which `tap` is applied (the `Try`):

> def tap[U](f: (A) => U): A

Answer (score 5):

You can tweak it even further using implicit class

```
def someMethod[A](f: => A): Try[A] = Try(f)

implicit class LogTry[A](res: Try[A]) {
  def log() = res match {
    case Success(s) => println("Success :) " + s); res
    case Failure(f) => println("Failure :( " + f); res
  }
}
```

Now you can call `someMethod` and on its result call `log` like this:

```
scala> someMethod(1/0).log
Failure :( java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

and

```
scala> someMethod(1).log
Success :) 1
```

Of course `println` method inside implicit class can be substituted with any logging you want.

Comment: You probably don't want to have type parameter `A` on `log`, since it shadows `A` of `LogTry`.

Comment: You also can just return `res` instead of returning `Success(s)` and `Failure(f)`, which create new instances.

Answer (score 1):

You used the term "exceptions" which is ambiguous. [`(java.lang.)Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Throwable.html) is the root of anything that can be placed behind the `throw` term. [`java.lang.Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Exception.html) is one of the two descendants of [`Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Throwable.html) (the other being [`java.lang.Error`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Error.html)). Further making this ambiguous is [`java.lang.RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/RuntimeException.html), a descendant of `Exception`, which is probably where you mostly want to spend your logging time (unless you are doing lower level application framework or hardware driver implementations).

Assuming you are wanting to log literally ALL instances of Throwable, then you would need something like this (NOT RECOMMENDED):

```
def logAtThrowable(f: => A): Try[A] =
  try
    Try(f) match {
      case failure @ Failure(throwable) =>
        log(s"Failure: {throwable.getMessage}")
        failure
      case success @ _ =>
        //uncomment out the next line if you want to also log Success-es
        //log(s"Success: {throwable.getMessage}")
        success
    }
  catch throwable: Throwable => {
    //!NonFatal pathway
    log(s"Failure: {throwable.getMessage}")
    throw throwable
  }
```

The external `try/catch` is required to capture all the `Throwable` instances which are filtered away by [`scala.util.control.NonFatal`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.util.control.NonFatal$) within the `Try`'s `try`/`catch` block.

That said...there is a Java/JVM rule: you should [*never* define a catch clause at the resolution of Throwable](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/strictexception.html) (again, unless you are doing lower level application framework or hardware driver implementations).

Following the intention of this rule, you would need to narrow the `Throwable` to you only emitted logging at the finer grained level, say something more refined, like `java.lang.RuntimeException`. If so, the code would look like this (recommended):

```
def logAtRuntimeException(f: => A): Try[A] =
  Try(f) match {
    case failure @ Failure(throwable) =>
      throwable match {
        case runtimeException: RuntimeException =>
          log(s"Failure: {runtimeException.getMessage}")
      }
      failure
    case success @ _ =>
      success
  }
```

In both code snippets above, you will notice that I used `match` as opposed to `.recoverWith`. This is to facilitate easily adding a re`throw` that works. It turns out that all the methods on `Try` are themselves also wrapped with `try`/`catch` blocks. This means that if you want to log the `Throwable` and then re`throw` it, if you are using one of the `Try` methods like `recoverWith`, the re`throw` is immediately recaught and placed into a `Failure` thereby completely undermining the value of the intentional re`throw`. By using `match`, the re`throw` is guaranteed to succeed as it remains *outside* any of the `Try` methods.

If you would like to see more of the rabbit holes around this particular area, I created a [blog post of my own exploration](http://fromjavatoscala.blogspot.com/2016/09/rethinking-scalautiltry.html).