# Scala on Android with scala.concurrent.Future do not report exception on system err/out

Tags: android, scala

We build an android application with Scala 2.11. We use scala.concurrent.Future for async background tasks. The problem is, that we do not see any exceptions in logcat if exceptions are thrown inside a Future block.

We already create an execution context with our own reporter:

```
lazy val reporter: (Throwable => Unit) = {
    t =>
      t.printStackTrace()
  }

  implicit lazy val exec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(
    new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 100, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
      new LinkedBlockingQueue[Runnable]), reporter)
```

Even if I set a breakpoint inside the reporter the debugger does never stop here, even if I force throwing of exceptions insde a Future {...} block.
What are we doing wrong

Comment: Any exceptions in Future transforms into Failure, have you tried onComplete/onFailure callbacks?

Comment: I tried to manually wrap the block inside the Future{..} with a Try(). Then I am able to do a pattern match and print something in case of a failure, but the problem is, that I have to do this in every place where I use an async future block. Taking a look at scala.concurrent.Promise I would expect at least a report to System.err:
try executor.execute(this) catch { case NonFatal(t) => executor reportFailure t }

Comment: That's redundant, considering `Future` is is basically a `Try`. And it catches the exceptions to `Failure`. You haven't posted any relevant code to the `Future`, so we can't recommend the correct way to handle it, other than saying *don't do that*. `Try` doesn't log caught exceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394291/scala-try-with-exception-logging

Comment: Setting a breakpoint in Promise gives me a failure:
Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: keys must match regex [a-z0-9_-]{1,64}: "userAvatar"), so I would expect the reporter gets his chance to handle the exception and log it to the logcat console

Comment: @LimbSoup : I know that's redundant (or better a different concept. Nobody should prohibit someone else from materializing exceptions in this way: Future[Try[V]]), it was just a try to see that I can log to the console there and see the exception.

Comment: @longliveenduro If you want materialize an error in the Future, better use scala `Either` or scalaz `\/` and then onSuccess callback -> Future[Error \/ Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment it looks like you simply didn't work with Future as needed. When some exception occurred during the Future computation it is transformed into Failure case (like Failure from Try, but in async context), e.g:

```
scala> Future { 10 / 0 }
res21: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@24f3ffd
```

As you can see there is no exception thrown or printed. To handle this exception you need to use callbacks, i.e `onComplete` or `onFailure`, e.g:

```
scala> res21.onFailure { case error => println(s"Error: ${ error.getMessage }") }
Error: / by zero
```

A great intro into Futures and Duality was given by the man with psychedelic T-Shirt Erik Meijer in the coursers [intro to Reactive Programming](https://www.coursera.org/course/reactive).

Comment: You're right, got the point. So I'm nearer to solve what I want. Is there any possibility to always create a Future{...} block with an default onFailure handler? (e.g. write the stacktrace to the console)? With that I wouldn't have to repeat always the same "last resort" exception logging code?

Comment: @longliveenduro You can make a function with a default handler for console output. Remember that you can "attach" any number of callbacks, so nothing stops you from attaching to onFailure callbacks and seven onSuccess/onComplete

Comment: If I understood you correctly you suggest a
def failureHandler = { case t: Throwable => t.printStackTrace() }
but then I always have to remember and repeat myself:
Future{...}.onFailure(failureHandler)
How can I get rid of this repetition?

Comment: Even more worse: Every time I do a map() on the future, I do have to reinstall the default failure handler on the mapped future?

Comment: @longliveenduro you can make a function `def spawn[A](action: => A) = Future(action).onFailure { ... }` then make future with `spawn`. As for `map`, no, there is no need in making additional callback.

Comment: Hmm...looking at Future.map implementation, there is a new Promise created and the future from this new promise does not have the desired onFailure Handler?

Comment: tried it out, I have to reinstall the failure handler after mapping the future to also observe the new code inside map...this is cumbersome

Comment: made a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453080/scala-futures-default-error-handler-for-every-new-created-or-mapped-exception