# Is it possible to do finally with Try?

Tags: scala, exception

I'm new to `Scala` and looked at source code of `Try::apply`

```
def apply[T](r: => T): Try[T] =
  try Success(r) catch {
    case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e)
  }
```

It simply catches non-fatal exceptions. But what if I need finally clause? Is it possible to emulate it with `Try` in a functional way? I mean something like

```
try{
   //acquire lock
   //do some
} finally {
  // release lock
}
```

with

```
Try{
   //acquire lock
   //do some
} 
//Now how to release?
```

Answer (score 5):

Something similar was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634455/simple-scala-pattern-for-using-try-with-resources-automatic-resource-manageme).

TLTR;
There is no standard way to do that with the Try monad.

The usual workaround is something like this:

```
def use[A <: { def close(): Unit }, B](resource: A)(code: A ⇒ B): B =
    try {
        code(resource)
    } finally {
        resource.close()
    }
```

That you can use like:

```
val path = Paths get "/etc/myfile"
use(Files.newInputStream(path)) { inputStream ⇒
    val firstByte = inputStream.read()
    ....
}
```

Another approach which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394291/scala-try-with-exception-logging?rq=1), implies that you "extend" the standard 'Try' by adding an additional method 'withRelease'

```
implicit class TryOps[A <: { def close(): Unit }](res: Try[A]) {
  def withRelease() = res match {
    case Success(s) => res.close(); res
    case Failure(f) => res.close(); res
  }
}
```

Then,

```
Try {
   val inputStream = Files.newInputStream(path))
   ...
   inputStream
}.withRelease()
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `Try` resolves to a value and it doesn't unwind the stack when something fails, you can simply perform the cleanup operations after `Try` has executed. For example:

```
val someLock = ??? // acquire some lock
val result = Try {
  // do something and return a result
}
someLock.release()
```

If you prefer, you can roll your own helper to keep everything into a single expression:

```
def withLock[A](f: Lock => A): Try[A] = {
  val lock = ??? // acquire the lock
  val res = f(lock)
  lock.release()
}
```

and then you can write:

```
val res = withLock { lock =>
 // some operation
}
```

This is usually refered to as *loan pattern*.

Comment: Why is `f: Lock => A`? Why pass the lock to the function if you're externally acquiring it? Seems like a by name thunk would do? `f: => A`

Comment: in case of a Lock, yes, probably. The pattern would fit better something like a connection that needs to be used inside the `block`.